# What should my shader look like when doing diffuse/directional lighting with skeletal matrices?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, lighting, vertex-shader

I've found examples online of how to perform diffusion lighting but I can't seem to find any regarding how things would change when using skeletal matrices.

Does anyone have an example I could look at?

I specifically used this page as an example to learn diffusion lighting:
http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=684

Answer (score 1):

No matter what kind of transformation you apply to your vertices, the most important thing is to keep consistent; know in what space you are performing your transformations. Assuming `object_matrix` is the transformation of your object and `camera_matrix` the view transformation:

```
vec4 pos = VertexPosition;
// pos is in object space

pos = object_matrix * pos;
// pos is now in world space

pos = camera_matrix * pos;
// view space
```

Light coordinates are usually in world space, in which case:

```
pos = object_matrix * pos;
// perform diffuse lighting computations here
pos = camera_matrix * pos;
```

If by "skeletal matrices" you refer to skeletal animation, they're done in object space.

Hope this helps.